# Does factoring by x-method always work?

Tags: factoring

Given the following function $R(x)$ [in pic] find the vertical, horizontal, oblique asymptotes. In order to find the asymptotes you need to reduce the function, so I did the following:

[image]

This is incorrect, the solution is $(2x-3)$; I noticed that the x method/ diamond method did not work here since the factors $(2x-3)(4x+7)$ did not multiply to $4x^2+x-21/2$ but rather $8x^2 +2x-21$, how this happens I do not know. Now, I understand there are many other ways of factoring this problem but I seem to have either made a mistake somewhere or have found a situation where the criss cross method does not work? I would like help finding out exactly what I did wrong, to help strengthen my math foundation.

Comment: The "x" in the diamond diagram should be a 1* this does not change my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrect in the following part:

$$8x^2+2x-21\ne 2(4x+7)(2x-3)$$

There is another part where you without reason, just add another $2$ also.

The correct factoring should be:$$R(x)=2x-3, \text{ where } x\ne-\dfrac{7}{4}$$

Comment: No, I wrote: $$8x^2+2x-21= 2((4x+7)(2x-3))$$ the reason another 2 comes up is because the 2 is distributed in both terms; the main issue I cant wrap my head around is the x method not working

Comment: Did you mean $2(4x^2+x-21/2)$, but that's really of no use @Sphygmomanometer

Comment: I  figured that I would factor out a 2 and then factor the smaller expression using the criss-cross method (which apparently doesnt work for this or I did something wrong)

Comment: `I figured that I would factor out a 2`. Then you also have to change the expression *it is being factored out of*. A very basic example would be saying that $2x$ isn't equal to $2(2x)$ @Sphygmomanometer

Comment: I did change the expression, is $$8x^2+2x-21= 2(4x^2+x-21/2)$$ not correct?

Comment: What you did *after* that is incorrect. Take a look at your factoring @Sphygmomanometer

Comment: Yes, I understand my factoring is incorrect but I correctly followed the rules of the diamond method, and this led me to incorrect factors. Therefore I am wondering if the x method has any restrictions since it led to me to a wrong answer.

Comment: The thing is, you did not use that method to factor $4x^2+x-\dfrac{21}2$, you used it to factor $8x^2+2x-21$, @Sphygmomanometer

Comment: No, I used 4x^2 +x -21/2; if you look at the cross, the -42 is derived from 4*-21/2 and the 1 (b value from x) .